# Does a nonnegative random variable whose expectation goes to zero converge to zero in probability?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $X_n$ be a nonnegative random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\leq \frac{\alpha}{n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, as $n \to \infty$, $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \to 0$. Is it possible to show that $X_n \to 0$ in probability?

**My try:**

To show $X_n \to 0$ in probability, one needs to show $\text{Prob}[|X_n-0|\geq \epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Since $X_n$ is a nonnegative random variable, one can write Markov's inequality as the following:

$$
\text{Prob}[|X_n-0|\geq \epsilon]=\text{Prob}[X_n\geq \epsilon]\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_n]}{\epsilon} \leq \frac{\alpha}{\epsilon n} 
$$

No matter how small $\epsilon$ is, one can get convergence in probability. Am I right?
Is there any way to get convergence in mean square($\ell_2$).

Comment: Your proof of convergence in probability is correct. You don't even know that second moments exist so you cannot prove mean square convergence.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: What if we know $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-\mathbb{E}[X_n]|^2]\leq \sigma^2$ for some $\sigma>0$?

Comment: @Sepide You still cannot say it converges to zero in mean square sense. Recall mean square error is bias^2 + variance. You need the variance to go to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the question in your comment above: Let $X_n$ take the values $0$ and $n$ with probabilities $1-\frac 1  {n^{2}}$ and $\frac 1  {n^{2}}$ respectively. Then $EX_n=\frac  1n$ and $E(X_n-EX_n)^{2}=1-\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ is bounded but $X_n$ does not converge in mean square.